# How to set button on navigationbar in tabbased application?

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I am working on a project which involves both kind of applications ie Navigation based and Tab based. All things are working perfectly. But what I want is, when I click on a particular tab then a button must be added to the navigation bar at the top to edit the table below it. I am able to draw the button but it is not affecting the tableview below it. When I do this in navigation based application it works perfectly. But it does not work in tab based.

So please tell me the way to add button at navigation bar in UI tab based application which appear only at particular tab.

tell me the sample code or any tutorial for it.

Comment: Add your code that is not working for you, and we will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For each tab embed a `UINavigationConrtoller`, and your own view controllers in them.

This way each tab will have its own navigation bar, and thus can have their own sets of bar items, titles, etc.

You generally never want to embed a `UITabBarController` in a `UINavigationController`, always the other way around.

Comment: I can understand your point but looking difficult for me. So can u plz provide me the sample code for it

Comment: @sanchitsingh: If this is hard for you, then you should read up on the  *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS*, because this is the very basics of iOS-programming: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

Comment: U r not interpreting it correctly. Actually I am adding view on clicking tab. So, dnt have the navigation bar inside the sub view